# Is it possible to disable ActiveAdmin authorization only for the tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, activeadmin, rspec-rails

I'm going to add some request tests for the formal testing ActiveAdmin page. Is it possible to disable ActiveAdmin authorization for these tests?

I need something like this for the test configuration:

```
  config.authentication_method = false
  config.current_user_method = false
```

Comment: I have many request tests without authorization and I don't want to make them like controller tests

Answer (score 0):

Never did it before but extending rspec DSL might work

For instance put this module to support folder

```
module ActiveAdminSpecHelper 
  def without_active_admin_auth
    authentication_method =  ActiveAdmin.application.authentication_method
    current_user_method = ActiveAdmin.application.current_user_method

    yield
  ensure
    ActiveAdmin.application.authentication_method = authentication_method
    ActiveAdmin.application.current_user_method = current_user_method
  end
end
```

and then

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  require 'support/active_admin_spec_helper'
  config.include ActiveAdminSpecHelper
end
```

After this u will be able to use it like

```
     it "does something" do
        without_active_admin_auth  do
          expect(something).to works_fine
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the easiest way is to include stubbed authorization with `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` and write the rest as usual

```rb
 # spec/controllers/admin/countries_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe Admin::CountriesController do
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
  render_views

  before { sign_in create(:admin_user) }

  describe 'GET #index' do
    it 'renders countries' do
      get :index

      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end
end
```